# why the longDoubleNum is Zeros

Tags: c

I'm beginner in C I have an issue in the output of my code here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

printf("float:      byte %lu\n",sizeof(float));
printf("double:     byte %lu\n",sizeof(double));
printf("long double:    byte %lu\n",sizeof(long double));

    float       floatNum =3.0/5.0;
    double      doubleNum=3.0/5.0;
    long double     longDoubleNum=3.0/5.0;


    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
    printf("float:       %1.4f      \n",floatNum);
    printf("double:          %1.4lf     \n",doubleNum);
    printf("long double:         %1.4Lf     \n",longDoubleNum);
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");

    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
    printf("float:       %1.20f     \n",floatNum);
    printf("double:          %1.20lf        \n",doubleNum);
    printf("long double:         %1.20Lf        \n",longDoubleNum);
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");

    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
    printf("float:       %1.60f     \n",floatNum);
    printf("double:          %1.60lf        \n",doubleNum);
    printf("long double:         %1.60Lf        \n",longDoubleNum);
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
}
```

here is the output:

```
float:      byte 4
double:     byte 8
long double:    byte 16
---------------------------------------
float:       0.6000     
double:          0.6000     
long double:         0.0000     
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
float:       0.60000002384185791000     
double:          0.59999999999999998000     
long double:         0.00000000000000000000     
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
float:       0.600000023841857910000000000000000000000000000000000000000000     
double:          0.599999999999999980000000000000000000000000000000000000000000     
long double:         0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000     
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: Technically your program exhibits *undefined behavior*. The correct format for `size_t` (the type of the value returned by `sizeof`) is `%zu`. Mismatching format and argument type leads to UB.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/V99RcY . What's your compiler, options, OS, timezone, eye color?

Comment: As for your problem, what *is* your problem?  Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], with emphasis on the *minimal* part, and tell us what output you *expected* to get.

Comment: @DavidRanieri No. A `float` value will become *promoted* to `double`, which is why both  `%f` and `%lf` can be used interchangeably for `float` and `double`. The `%Lf` format is correct for `long double`. See e.g. [this `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: you may want to do `longDoubleNum = 3.0L/5.0L;` otherwise it's a division done with `double` precision. https://ideone.com/dRdt8m

Comment: @DavidRanieri Historically there was no different printf conversion specifier for `float` or `double`, both used `%f`, because default argument promotion made the argument `double` anyway. This did however make printf inconsistent with scanf, so from C99 and beyond `%lf` is also allowed for `double`. As for `long double`, it was always `%Lf` with upper case L.

Comment: @Ragaey M.Ragaa Let me guess, you are using Visual Studio or Mingw? (Mingw is the Windows gcc port used by for example Codeblocks, DevC++ and a bunch of other IDEs)

Comment: @Lundin Visual Studio has an 8 byte long double (same as double).

Comment: @AdrianMole Yeah but it goes apes**t if you try to give it conversion specifiers from the year 1999 or later... On mingw you can un-ape it by using `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` before including stdio.h. I could reproduce the problem with mingw and the #define fixed it.

Comment: Okay guys I'm Using eclipse and gnu11 and the latest version of C in MinGw I tried all Your answers still gives me 0.0000000000

Comment: @RagaeyM.Ragaa Pretty sure that's the problem. Try the code in the answer I posted.

Comment: @Lundin OMG it Worked man LOL after all of that You right I added this line before libraries #define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Windows compiler that in turn uses Microsoft's (non) standard C libraries, you will get exactly the problem you describe. You will also get a warning along the lines of:

> warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]

This is because Microsoft's lib (barely) conforms to the year 1990 version of C (C90), not to the year 1999 (C99) or later versions. This means that it doesn't recognize any printf/scanf conversion specifiers such as `%Lf` that were added in C99, but will happily produce a broken binary executable regardless.

With the Mingw/gcc compiler, you can fix the issue like this:

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
#include <stdio.h>
...
```

With MSVC you can't fix it afaik, so consider replacing that one with a different compiler.